# fetch the names of a the tables in mysql database with pdo and php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been attempting to get the table names from my mysql database with pdo and no matter what I try the only thing I get returned is the word Array for each table instead of the name.

I have tried all of the pdo fetch_* and one of them returned a 1 for each table while the others either return an error or the word Array. It does not matter which example below: $st or $rt

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'";        
        $st = $db->query($sql);
        $st->execute();

        //$rt = $db->query("show tables");
        //$rt->execute();

        while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row.'<br>';
        }
```

Thanks in advance
Pete

Comment: Instead of `echo $row.'<br>';` you could just do a `print_r($row)` or a `var_dump($row)` as long as you are just interested in seeing what is in the returned array, and are not trying to use the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this return a multi dimensional array. So you cannot outright echo it. Since you used `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` flag, it will return an associative array which in turn you must access its proper index.

```
while($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['TABLE_NAME'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Sidenote: I don't think `$st->execute();` belong in there since this is not using a prepared statement. I think its safe to ditch that part.

Comment: Thanks... @Ghost... that did it. I knew it was simple. I tried that but must of left out the apostrophes or somethin dumb like that

Comment: @petebolduc yes, that `$row` will hold value inside it as it returns an array. im glad this helped

Comment: You were correct @Ghost... thanks again... that was a couple of hours I won't get back lol... so simple